# Visual Studio doesn't put binaries of Unity project to output folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, build

I’m working on a solution containing default Unity project (*Assembly-CSharp*).

**I added a test project to the solution** with a reference to *Assembly-CSharp*. According to IntelliSense, the test project does see the types from *Assembly-CSharp*, however **when I’m trying to build the solution, I’m getting the following error**:

`Metadata file 'MyProjectFolder\Temp\bin\Debug\Assembly-CSharp.dll' could not be found.`

Thus, **I'm not able to run unit tests on my Unity project**.

Indeed, when I’m building the Unity projects, the `.\Temp\bin\Debug` folder remains empty even though the build is recognized as successful by VS.

Comment: For what platform are you building? Is your view of 4 projects just the view you get when you open a script in unity? Its important to know because in some cases it doesnt help to add a project, like you did. And are you doing this because you want to write unit tests?If yes, there is tonne of guides online..

Comment: When opening a new Unity project's sources in VS, the solution indeed contains only Assembly-CSharp (it wasn't like that in the past I believe). I adjusted the question to make it simpler. Still, I think you overlooked my real issue — it doesn't have anything to do with learning how to write unit tests, it's about any other assemblies (for example unit test projects) not being able to use my Unity project assembly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The problem is caused by `Disable the full build of projects` setting** which is new in Unity Tools extension. It prevents the binaries to be created, which speeds up situations when they're not actually being used, like when starting the debugger.

[image]

## **Turning this setting off in Visual Studio settings fixes the issue. Now all build products are placed in `./Temp/bin/Debug` folder and I can run unit tests.**

#### Feature request

I made a feature request to VS to make it possible to define this setting at solution level, so that you can have 1 solution for speed and 1 for unit testing. I hope it will get enough votes up: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/798543/make-it-possible-to-manipulate-the-disable-the-ful.html

Comment: I did not know about this setting. Thanks for clarifying on the matter.

Comment: Amazing, in doing this they totally break the expectations of the ProjectReference Protocol https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/master/documentation/ProjectReference-Protocol.md and as per usual crickets on DeveloperCommunity thanks for documenting your findings.

Comment: Thank you, I looked into this for quite a while before finding your answer!

Comment: This option seems to have disapeared now

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and regenerate project files did the trick.

Edit => Preferences => External Tools => Regenerate Project Files